# (Android) Inicializar un objeto view en un Button e ImageButton

Tags: java, android, botón

¡Buenas!

Abro este tema por si podéis ayudarme.  Resulta que tengo que crear un objeto que hereda de View, pero dependiendo de un valor debe ser o un Button o un ImageButton. El problema es que he probado casteando y directamente creando el botón o el imagebutton y nada. El código que adjunto es de lo que tengo ahora. El caso es que no se cómo pasar de un View a Button o ImageButton, ya que estos dos elementos son View.

Tras las modificaciones, quiero aclarar que me gustaría saber cómo, una clase que hereda de View, puede convertirse en un Button o un ImageButton, ya que con herencia llega, solo eso.

Clase casilla

```
public class Casilla extends View{

private int contenido;

public Casilla(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public int getContenido() {
    return contenido;
}

public void setContenido(int contenido) {
    this.contenido = contenido;
}
```

}

Clase Tablero (método llenarTablero)

```
private void llenarTablero() {
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;i++){
            if(matriz[i][j]==-1){
                casillas[i][j]= new Casilla(context);
            }
            else{
                casillas[i][j]= new Casilla(context);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

De lo que recuerdo que he intentado, he hecho esto, que es lo que creía que funcionaría.

```
private void llenarTablero() {
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;i++){
            if(matriz[i][j]==-1){
                //casillas[i][j]=new ImageButton(context);
                casillas[i][j]= (ImageButton)new Casilla(context);
            }
            else{
                //casillas[i][j]=new Button(context);
                casillas[i][j]= (Button)new Casilla(context);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias por las respuesta.

Comment: Pon el código de lo que hayas probado para poder ayudarte mejor y para que la pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos, es importante lo que comenta Marc, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado!, saludos!

Comment: Modificado, espero que sirva.

Comment: @CarlosBustos gracias Carlos, una pregunta como creas casillas[i][j] ?

Comment: Lo creo como una matriz de la clase Casilla. Casilla casillas[][], poniéndole un tamaño de 8x8.

Answer (score 1):

Tu instancia esta mal creada, prueba algo como esto:

```
Casilla boton = new Casilla(this);
Button btn = (Button) boton;

Casilla imageBoton = new Casilla(this);
ImageButton iBtn = (ImageButton) imageBoton;
```

Comment: me parece que serían tipos incompatibles, Casilla extiende de View.

Comment: Eso me he supuesto, pero debería de valer ya que Button e ImageButton vienen de View. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?